# How can I validate a decimal number with a regular expression

Tags: karate

I have the following json:

```json
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jack",
    "salary": 23.03
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Luke",
    "salary": 0.00
    }
]
```

I need to validate that there are only 2 digits after the decimal point.

I'm doing this:

```
* def salary = $response..salary
* karate.appendTo(salary)
* def strs = karate.map(salary, function(x){ return x + '' })
* match each strs == '#regex [0-9].+\\.[0-9]{2}'
```

The validation is correct when I have salaries of, for example, "23.40" or "12.30". The problem is that, when I have a 0, or 2, or 3, the validation throws the following errors:

[1st error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNRk7.png)

[2nd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRb2l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel trying to validate the shape of a number type in JSON is a waste of time, numbers are the same even when formatted differently. And the moment you attempt a conversion to string, you have no control over decimal points. For example, try this:

```
* def response = [ { "id": 1, "name": "Jack", "salary": 23.03 }, { "id": 2, "name": "Luke", "salary": 0.00 } ]
* def salaries = response.map(x => x.salary + '')
* print salaries
```

You get: `[ "23.03", "0" ]`

So I would say what you are trying is not possible or supported.